# SQL query when using distinct

Tags: sql-server-2005, distinct

I want to know can I use distinct in different columns when writing a SQL query. If so then what is the statement if I have employee table that has id,name, salary, addr as columns

Answer (score 3):

No

Distinct works across the whole tuple.

You cannot have

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name), salary, addr, Id from employee
```

If you want to group by salary you could do something like

```
SELECT salary, name,  addr, Id from employee
GROUP BY name,  addr, Id
```

To expand further

When you use distinct it eliminates duplicates of the whole result set

So if your table is like so

1 'John' '1 my street' '$1000'

2 'Janet''1 my street' '$1000'

and you call

```
SELECT DISTINCT addr, salary FROM employee
```

you will get 1 result

> '1 my street' '$1000'

but if you want to call

```
SELECT DISTINCT addr, salary, **name** FROM employee
```

you will get 2 results

> 'John' '1 my street' '$1000'
>   'Janet''1 my street' '$1000'

You cannot say get me distinct salary and address, but with different names. it doesn't make sense

Comment: can you explain more i cann't get what you saied
is this mean that name,salary,addr are dictinct with writing dictinct in after select word